# Creating a new PC variable based on PCA loadings

Tags: r, machine-learning, pca

I am trying to find variables which would be good predictors for the "stool" variable in my data.  I was thinking I would use PCA to create a new variable which accounted for most of the variance in stool based on the other variables in the data.

As I understand you look at pc3$loadings to find the component (comp.1) which accounts for most of the variance in the data.  Then you can look at the variables that make up component one.  Do you just multiply the variables by the coefficients from loadings to create the new variable, like I have for "NewVar"?  That would be all the parts that make up comp.1 except for the part that includes stool.

Code:

```
pc3<-princomp(datadf, cor=TRUE)
pc3$loadings

NewVar<-(-0.473)*duck+(-0.468)*pigeon+(-0.677)*hawk
```

Data:

```
datadf<-dput(datadf)
structure(list(stool = c(11, 14, 17, 5, 5, 5.5, 8, 5.5, 
6.5, 8.5, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 7, 6, 7, 7, 5, 6, 9, 9, 6.5, 9, 3.5, 
2, 15, 2.5, 17, 5, 5.5, 7, 6, 3.5, 6, 9.5, 5, 7, 4, 5, 4, 9.5, 
3.5, 5, 4, 4, 9, 4.5), duck = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), pigeon = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), hawk = c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 
2L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 
5L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 2L)), .Names = c("stool", "duck", 
"pigeon", "hawk"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(8L, .Names = "8", class = "omit"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since each principal component is represented as linear combination of the original variable you can just multiply your variables like you did.

Also note that you can access loadings of the first PC by typing

```
pc3$loadings[, 1]
```